# How can I create a "product queue" for a subscription service?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a "product queue" for a monthly subscription service.

- The user can add a product to each monthly slot in his queue, only allowing one product per month.
- The system creates a new order each month with the selected product.
- The order is automatically created on a specific day in the month.
- Product selection can be changed, deleted or suffled between month slots.

My idea is to create an "product_queue" table where all the selected product_id's are stored by queue_month and user_id, but I have no idea how to make this work in the background, as the orders need to be created on their own on the specific order day.
The website has currently a generic cart system using $_SESSION, but I think this can't be rebuild to a queue system.

I have searched on stack overflow and other sites, but I can't find any info for this specific problem.

Comment: Background as in "cron job?" There's also the MySQL [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html).

Comment: seems like you need a cron job to achieve what you want

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is basically correct. The one thing that you are missing for the "queue" to work are "cron jobs". Cron jobs allow you to schedule a script in a predefined interval.

In a most basic scenario, you want to write a script / entry point for your application that will process all orders that are due for that specific day, based on the product_queue table.

I hope this can lead you to the right solution.